# Is it possible update a shapefile instead create a new one when using Processing?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Using Processing to add or calculate a field it's always necessary create a new shapefile? Is there a way to just update and keep using same layer?

Comment: Edit Features “In Place” Using QGIS Spatial Operations Campaign https://north-road.com/edit-features-in-place-using-qgis-spatial-operations-campaign/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved in recent versions when add option to 'edit in-place' in Processing Toolbox.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-processing-in-place-layer-modifier